# Disabling .NET 6 features per default

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When creating a new project in VS 2022 with .NET 6, following new features are added automatically:

- Top-Level Statements
- Implicit Usings and Nullable References

Is there a way to create a .NET 6 project

- without top-level-statements (a workaround other than creating a .NET 5 project & changing project type to .NET 6)
- with implicit usings & nullable references disabled (without editing the project file each time after project creation)

Comment: Make your own template or See [Use the old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style)

Comment: You can now disable top level statement it in VS 2022 17.3.0 (Preview 1.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A. Nullable reference types - keep them on

I suggest keeping nullable reference types on. I'd echo [Embracing nullable reference types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/) and say that all new code should use it. Here's the original statement:

> When .NET 5 rolls around, if we feel the nullable rollout phase has been a success, I could see us turning the feature on by default for new projects in Visual Studio. If the ecosystem is ready for it, there is no reason why any new code should ignore the improved safety and reliability you get from nullability annotations!

## B. Top level statements

### Update May 2022

VS2022 17.3.0 (Preview 1.1) supports disabling top-level statements when creating console apps:
[image]

---

### Original

Targetting the .net5 framework and editing the project file is the official way to use the *old program style*.

Please see [Use the old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style).

> While a .NET 6 console app template generates the new style of top-level statements programs, using .NET 5 doesn't. By creating a .NET 5 project, you'll receive the old program style. Then, you can edit the project file to target .NET 6 but retain the old program style for the Program.cs file.

and

> The features that make the new program simpler are top-level statements, global using directives, and implicit using directives.

BTW. Cast your vote on the official [Should the console project template use top-level statements](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27420) directly in gihub:

[image]

Comment: The choice is an illusion unfortunately. Creating projects like "Blazor Web App" will create more than one project files, and the secondary ones seem to not respect the checkbox "Do not use top-level statements". I also don't get why such clear feedback where removing this feature even got more votes than providing a user option is not respected. Now it's another feature that needs maintenance and bug reports and whatnot. For zero gain besides complete beginners getting confronted with slightly less boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this post to see if it would still be possible to have the `Main()` method when creating projects via command prompt. Looks like there is! as of .NET 6.0 SDK one can add the `--use-program-main` command line option when creating new projects as follows:

```
dotnet new console --use-program-main
```

Source: [Use the old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style)

Answer (score 1):

Just check 'Do not use top-level statements' when creating asp.net core web application. I'm not sure, but this top-level statements introduced just more confusion than anything else.

Microsoft please keep things simple and useable as they were. A lot of new c# features are becoming like in typescript/javascript or node.js style. I get that, but add things that are clear and usable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an .editorconfig and add the following line to prevent top level statements from being included by default

`csharp_style_prefer_top_level_statements = false:error`

I think this is another net5/6 feature that can be constrained the same way

`csharp_prefer_simple_using_statement = false:error`